# Do I require a visa with my Belgian refugee travel document to enter Macedonia?

Tags: visas, schengen, macedonia

I have a belgian travel document for refugees and residence in Belgium. Can I enter Macedonia/FYROM visa-free or do I need to apply for a visa before entry?

Comment: Do you have _permanent_ residence in Belgium?

Comment: I guess not since my residence card expires in 2020.

Comment: @Tee the expiration of a document does not per se imply that the right of residence itself is temporary.  Does it say for example "tijdelijk verblijf" or "séjour temporaire"?

Comment: Strange, refugees generally get permanent residence (séjour illimité) as soon as their refugee applications are approved. The _card_ will still need to be renewed every five years though. See [this document](http://www.stjosse.irisnet.be/pdf/divers/titres_de_sejour.pdf); if your card has a B or a D in the indicated position, then it is evidence of permanent residence.

Comment: While mine is B and according to your link it is illimité.

Comment: There is one more issue, what is your previous nationality?

Comment: Sudanese is my previous nationality.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to stay for more than 15 days at a time, or for more than 3 months in a 6-month period, you do not require a visa:

> Third countries with permanent stay in an EU member country or signatory country of the Schengen Agreement may stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of Macedonia, and the total amount of the subsequent stays in the Republic of Macedonia must not be longer than 3 (three) months within a six-months period, starting from the date of the first entry.

Source: http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php/en/for-foreign-nationals/information-on-visa-entry-to-the-republic-of-macedonia/entry-in-the-republic-of-macedonia-for-schengen-visa-holders

If you want to exceed those limits, then you will need to apply for a visa.

Comment: Have you found an error in Timatic? It tells me that: "Visa required, except for Passengers with a permanent residence permit issued by Belgium for a maximum stay of 90 days."

Comment: @MichaelHampton perhaps I have.